# PhalconPHP + Percona

Tags: phalcon, percona

Does anyone have Phalcon PHP working with Percona?  Is it fairly simple/straightforward to set up?  Are there any drivers or interfaces for it currently or will I need to roll my own?

Any thoughts/help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percona is a fork of MySql, it does everything MySql does + some additional (apparently?) cool things all using old good sql. It works with PHP perfectly fine via PDO, and hence the Phalcon also uses PDO you have everything you need. ASAIK, with the out of box configuration you simply need to stop your MySql server and start Percona's with the same schema (if you are migrating), they use the same ports, so the configuration also shouldn't change.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you, once again, for your help, Ian.  Are you a Phalcon dev, perchance?

Comment: Only a minor contributor ;)